# Como posso salvar essas duas funções do python em arquivos distintos?

Tags: python, arquivo

Eu criei duas funções, uma para analisar os números primos e outra para analisar os números perfeitos e gostaria de saber como poderia salvar os resultados obtidos para os primos em um arquivo e os outros resultados obtidos para os perfeitos em outro arquivo.

```
print ('Olá.\nPor favor, digite um primeiro valor para verificar os números primos e um segundo valor para verificar os números perfeitos')

def primo(n):
    if n< 2:
        return False
    
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i == 0:
            return False

    return True


valorminimo = 2
valordigitado = int(input('Valor para verificação dos números primos: '))

print('\nOs números primos até', valordigitado, 'são: ')
for i in range(valorminimo, valordigitado+1):
    if primo(i):
        print(i, end=' ')

def numero_perfeito(n):
    
    if n< 1:
        return False

    somaperfeito = 0
    
    for i in range(1,n):
        if n%i==0:
            somaperfeito += i

    return somaperfeito == n


valorminimo = 0
valordigitado = int(input('\nValor para verificação dos números perfeitos: '))


print('\nOs números perfeitos existentes até', valordigitado, 'são: ')
for i in range(valorminimo, valordigitado+1):
    if numero_perfeito(i):
        print(i, end=' ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar `open('nome_do_arquivo.txt','w')`, `f.writelines()` e `f.close()`. Isso para cada arquivo que quiser escrever.

```
print ('Olá.\nPor favor, digite um primeiro valor para verificar os números primos e um segundo valor para verificar os números perfeitos')

def primo(n):
    if n< 2:
        return False
    
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i == 0:
            return False

    return True


valorminimo = 2
valordigitado = int(input('Valor para verificação dos números primos: '))

print('\nOs números primos até', valordigitado, 'são: ')

f = open('primos.txt','w')
for i in range(valorminimo, valordigitado+1):
    if primo(i):
        print(i, end=' ')
        f.writelines(str(i)+' ')
f.close()


def numero_perfeito(n):
    
    if n< 1:
        return False

    somaperfeito = 0
    
    for i in range(1,n):
        if n%i==0:
            somaperfeito += i

    return somaperfeito == n


valorminimo = 0
valordigitado = int(input('\nValor para verificação dos números perfeitos: '))

f = open('perfeitos.txt','w')
print('\nOs números perfeitos existentes até', valordigitado, 'são: ')
for i in range(valorminimo, valordigitado+1):
    if numero_perfeito(i):
        print(i, end=' ')
        f.writelines(str(i)+' ')
f.close()
```

Claro que existem outras alternativas mas creio que essa seja uma maneira simples.